# Variable passed through the baseclass not giving an IllegalArgumentException of its parentclass

Tags: java

The following is my code one of the classes called car (base class) which is being inherited by ford and Honda(sub classes). In the main class (which is not car) I am printing out the variable cars though ford and Honda which are inheriting cars from car class. The issue I am facing is if the cars is set to any negative number it don't show this IllegalaArgumentException.

```
public class car{
 protected long cars;

 public void setCars(long number) {
    if(cars < 0)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("cars must be ≥ 0!");
             cars = number ;
 }
}

public class honda extends car{
 public String toString(){
    String st = "HONDA" + "no of cars : " + cars ;
    return st;
 }
}

public class main{
 public static void main(String[] args){

    car[] cscar = new car[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
      cscar[0] = new honda(-100);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: i hope you are calling the method `setCars()` with the stated value

Comment: There's no way of knowing what you're doing or what your code not shown looks like. I agree with @DanielPryden -- show us your best [mcve] if you seriously want and need help.

Comment: Complete code will be not be allowed on this website as its a long program

Comment: And no one is asking for "complete code". Again we're asking for a decent [mcve]. If you took the time to read the link before replying, you would already have known this and would not have made your reply above. Again, if you need serious help and need it now, read the link.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels now make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear which problem you are facing, but seems you want to achieve `IllegalArgumentException` to be thrown in sub-classes when number of cars is negative.

So here's what should work:

1. The function `setCars` should be slightly changed: currently you are setting number of cars to negative number, and then throwing the exception. Instead you should check the number before setting it:

   ```
   public void setCars(long number) {
       if(cars < 0)
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("cars must be ≥ 0!");

       cars = number ;
   }
   ```
2. I assume that `cars` is a variable in base class. So it should be private, and it should only be set via `setCars` function anywhere in car class. Do not ever set it directly:

   ```
   public class Car {

       private long cars;

       // ...
   }
   ```
3. Sub-classes should either not overwrite `setCars` at all, or (if they need to overwrite), call parent method first:

   ```
   public class Honda {

       // setCars function is not overwritten here, 
       // so parent function will be called
   }

   public class Ford {

       // setCars function is overwritten here, 
       // but parent function is called first:

       @Override
       public void setCars(long number) {
           super.setCars(number);
           // if we've got here, then exception was not thrown
           // so function can do something else
       }
   }
   ```

Alternatively you can set parent function as `public final void setCars`, so that nobody can overwrite it at all

Above code will produce the desired result:

```
Honda honda = new Honda();
honda.setCars(-5); // will throw the exception
```

Comment: I think i am doing what ever you said but still able to print negative values. Thanks for replying

Comment: the difference in your code is that you are trying to initiate `cars` in constructor (`new honda(-100)`). I don't see constructor in the code you pasted, but if you want to do that, your constructor should look like this: `public Car(long number) { setCars(number); }` and `setCars` must be final in this case